# How to map an URL having querystring parameters in urlmapping.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Grails/Groovy. Please bear with me if this is a silly question.

I am trying to map an URL having querystring parameters in `urlmapping.groovy`, something like,

```
"/rest/employees?empno=123&dept=delivery"(controller:"employees", action="emp")
```

The values `123` and `delivery` are dynamic values. In other words, this could be anything that the user can use.

Apparently this syntax is not correct. What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Just leave `/rest/employees"(controller:"employees", action="emp")` and you'll get your query parameters as `params.empno` and `params.dept` in your action

Answer (score 3):

@splix answer is correct. If you want to use a restfull url, you could do something like

```
"/rest/employees/$empno/$dept"
```

instead. Otherwise just leave out the part after "?" as said. In your controller you will still get `params.empno` and `params.dept`

[Read more here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings)

Comment: it is an example of path params not a query params